# After migration to 2013 in OFFICE 365, Site UI is not proper, Black Hover is there

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, css

I have Migrated one site from 2010 to 2013.
We have used Evaluation site to test migration, and resolved most Issues.
once we have migrated the site, we came across one UI issue which was not part of Evaluation site.
[image]

If you can provide any help,
Primary investigation says Microsoft has changed their CSS

https://prod.msocdn.com/3.06.5615.1/en-US/css/O365ShellCore.css

the class which are responsible for the bad UI are as belows.

```
    .o365button {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border-width: 0;
color: #333;
cursor: pointer !important;
font: 14px 'Segoe UI','Segoe WP','Segoe UI WPC',Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
padding: 0;}




    .o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo button.o365cs-spo-topbarMenuOpen, .o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo button.o365cs-spo-topbarHover, .o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo a.o365cs-spo-topbarMenuOpen, .o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo a.o365cs-spo-topbarHover {
background-color: yellow;
border-color: #dedede;
color: #000;}
```

Has any of you have encountered the same issue?

What is the workaround to make your site safe from future Microsoft changes?

Comment: I cannot provide any advice on how to safeguard your site from future Microsoft blunders, but the black drop down of doom is their latest one: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/258977/793376.aspx#793363

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is again back to normal.
It seems Microsoft has done some correction.

@wjervis, Thanks for adding link which shows there are other people also affected.

Comment: Will Someone give details, why this has been downvoted?  
It will really help me learn things better, and stop me doing same mistakes again.